# How to enable guake at startup using systemd

Tags: systemd

i made my service

```
/etc/systemd/system/guake.service
```

containing

```
[Unit]
Description=Start guake 

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash guake

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

then i did

```
systemctl start guake.service 
systemctl status guake.service
```

but i get

● guake.service - Start guake
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/guake.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Thu 2015-07-16 21:14:36 SAST; 4s ago
  Process: 10785 ExecStart=/bin/bash guake (code=dumped, signal=SEGV)
 Main PID: 10785 (code=dumped, signal=SEGV)

Jul 16 21:14:36 tawanda-pc bash[10785]: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/**init**.py:57: GtkWarning: could...isplay
Jul 16 21:14:36 tawanda-pc bash[10785]: warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
Jul 16 21:14:36 tawanda-pc bash[10785]: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keybinder/**init**.py:26: GtkWarning: IA__gdk...failed
Jul 16 21:14:36 tawanda-pc bash[10785]: from _keybinder import *
Jul 16 21:14:36 tawanda-pc bash[10785]: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keybinder/**init**.py:26: GtkWarning: IA__gdk...failed
Jul 16 21:14:36 tawanda-pc bash[10785]: from _keybinder import *
Jul 16 21:14:36 tawanda-pc systemd[1]: guake.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV
Jul 16 21:14:36 tawanda-pc systemd[1]: guake.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 16 21:14:36 tawanda-pc systemd[1]: guake.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Jul 16 21:14:36 tawanda-pc systemd-coredump[10790]: Process 10785 (python2) of user 0 dumped core.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.

I also tried setting `WantedBy=multi-user.target` but it has the same error

i am runnig arch linux, how do i get this to startup, thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're probably looking at running Guake as an application inside your user session and not as a root application. Thus you should look at `systemd --user` services ([ArchWiki: systemd/User](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User)).

Then, Guake is an X11 appliation and thus requires a running X11 session. systemd does not (yet) handle X11 sessions, thus the best option is to look at the features offered by you desktop environment to auto launch programs upon session startup. As far as I know this can easily be done with KDE and GNOME.